# MODLS of order 12

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I found a MODLS group of order 12 consisting of four diagonal Latin squares

0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
1  3  5  0  9  7  4  2 11  6  8 10
4  9  8  6  1 11  0 10  5  3  2  7
5  7  1  2 11  3  8  0  9 10  4  6
7  2  3  5 10  0 11  1  6  8  9  4
11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
3  0  7  1  6  2  9  5 10  4 11  8
6  4 10  9  0  8  3 11  2  1  7  5
2  5  0  7  8  1 10  3  4 11  6  9
8 11  4 10  5  9  2  6  1  7  0  3
9  6 11  4  3 10  1  8  7  0  5  2
10  8  6 11  2  4  7  9  0  5  3  1

0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
2  5  0  7  8  1 10  3  4 11  6  9
3  0  7  1  6  2  9  5 10  4 11  8
11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
5  7  1  2 11  3  8  0  9 10  4  6
10  8  6 11  2  4  7  9  0  5  3  1
9  6 11  4  3 10  1  8  7  0  5  2
8 11  4 10  5  9  2  6  1  7  0  3
6  4 10  9  0  8  3 11  2  1  7  5
4  9  8  6  1 11  0 10  5  3  2  7
7  2  3  5 10  0 11  1  6  8  9  4
1  3  5  0  9  7  4  2 11  6  8 10

0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
6  4 10  9  0  8  3 11  2  1  7  5
7  2  3  5 10  0 11  1  6  8  9  4
4  9  8  6  1 11  0 10  5  3  2  7
2  5  0  7  8  1 10  3  4 11  6  9
8 11  4 10  5  9  2  6  1  7  0  3
10  8  6 11  2  4  7  9  0  5  3  1
3  0  7  1  6  2  9  5 10  4 11  8
1  3  5  0  9  7  4  2 11  6  8 10
5  7  1  2 11  3  8  0  9 10  4  6
11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
9  6 11  4  3 10  1  8  7  0  5  2

0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
7  2  3  5 10  0 11  1  6  8  9  4
8 11  4 10  5  9  2  6  1  7  0  3
10  8  6 11  2  4  7  9  0  5  3  1
4  9  8  6  1 11  0 10  5  3  2  7
5  7  1  2 11  3  8  0  9 10  4  6
11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
9  6 11  4  3 10  1  8  7  0  5  2
3  0  7  1  6  2  9  5 10  4 11  8
1  3  5  0  9  7  4  2 11  6  8 10
6  4 10  9  0  8  3 11  2  1  7  5
2  5  0  7  8  1 10  3  4 11  6  9

https://boinc.multi-pool.info/latinsquares/forum_thread.php?id=120&postid=2217

Is there a known MODLS group of order 12 consisting of five diagonal Latin squares?

Comment: Some constructions for t pairwise orthogonal diagonal Latin squares based on difference matrices
R. Abel, Yang Li
Published 2015
Computer Science, Mathematics
Discret. Math.
https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/7/ocr-ajc-v7-p87.pdf

"Theorem 1.1
There exist five pairwise orthogonal diagonal Latin squares of every
order n where n > 164. Order 2 ≤ n ≤ 7 are impossible; the only orders for which
the existence is undecided are:

10 12 14 15 18 20 21 22 24 26
28 30 33 34 35 36 38 39 40 42
44 45 46 48 50 51 52 54 55 60
62 66 68 69 70 74 76 82 84 90
98 106 164"

Comment: I found the fifth square for the MODLS group I found, containing four diagonal Latin squares (see question).

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
3 0 7 1 6 2 9 5 10 4 11 8
2 5 0 7 8 1 10 3 4 11 6 9
1 3 5 0 9 7 4 2 11 6 8 10
6 4 10 9 0 8 3 11 2 1 7 5
7 2 3 5 10 0 11 1 6 8 9 4
4 9 8 6 1 11 0 10 5 3 2 7
5 7 1 2 11 3 8 0 9 10 4 6
10 8 6 11 2 4 7 9 0 5 3 1
9 6 11 4 3 10 1 8 7 0 5 2
8 11 4 10 5 9 2 6 1 7 0 3
11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

https://boinc.multi-pool.info/latinsquares/forum_thread.php?id=120&postid=2367
Unfortunately, this is not diagonal Latin square.